# Java Invoke Static Method in Dynamic Class Without Instance

Tags: java

I am trying to add a dynamic logging class to my program (for changing where log messages go e.g. System.out or a file). It extends the base abstract `Logger` class which has a static method `log(String)`. Is it possible to set the logger class and then invoke the log method without making an instance of the logger or using reflection?

Something like this:

```
    public class MainController {
        private Class<? extends Logger> mLogger;

        // ...

        public void setLogger(Class<? extends Logger> logger) {
            mLogger = logger;
        }

        public Class<? extends Logger> getLogger() {
            return mLogger;
        }

        // ...
    }

    public class BrokenTest {
        // ...
        private void showErrorMessage(String message) {
            mMainController.getLogger().log(message); // Can't call .log on Class
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you considered using Apache Commons Logging? See http://commons.apache.org/logging/. Not really answering your question, but that would help you forward. You would not face these kind of problems, and would certainly not need to use reflection...

Comment: @KMaertens Don't need an actual implementation, just the possibility the change the log output location. The library will be used on Android so I need a wrapper for the android Log class. On CLI it will just be a System.out wrapper.

Comment: I must have missed something, what's wrong with just keeping an instance of `Logger` in a static field?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "Dynamic Class"?

Comment: @lynks Nothing specific, I thought it would be nicer to keep it static if possible.

Comment: @BheshGurung As in a variable containing the logger class that have different values (rather than knowing the class in advance and using Logger.log("message"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Method method = mMainController.getLogger().getMethod("log", String.class);
Object result = method.invoke(null, message);
```

This will call a static method named `log` with a `String` parameter on the class returned by `getLogger()`.

**UPDATE**

But from your description, I believe using an *interface* and separate *implementations* would be better. This way, you can work with instances and normal polymorphic calls.

Comment: Yeah this way is possible, but was hoping some way without reflection. It'd probably be easier to just keep an instance if that was the case.

Comment: Yes, I think an instance method would be much better.... Your base class would make more sense that way.